# Wake-Up Radio plugin/simulation for Cooja

Tags: simulation, sensors, contiki, radio-transmission

I am trying to implement wake-up radio feature for wireless sensor networks using Cooja. Since, I am new to Cooja, does anyone have done this before or has any idea how to implement it in Cooja as a plugin.

Wake-up radio (WuR) is basically a secondary radio attached to the main mote and can be in-band or out-of band radio. This WuR is a very low power (nA) device and can be kept on for the full time and will monitor the channel. Upon valid data to be transferred,it will send a wake-up call to the other wake-up receiver which will then wake up the main mote via interrupt pin.

It will be really helpful if anyone can provide some guidelines as how to implement this secondary radio.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

Cooja is designed to support 802.15.4 radios. If you only need in-band wakeup you can just extend one of the existing radios by monitoring changes in signal strengt. This is probably easier then writing a second radio.

If you want something out of band (meaning not 802.15.4) you will need to add some parallel radio - or extend one of the existing models - and radios. There is some stuff about Cooja and PLC. That might be a good starting point.

Basically you must decide if you can get along with extending the existing stuff or need to implement something in parallel - and especially for which platform. Fortunately Cooja is one of the better structured projects (although some of the actual code is pretty ugly). Thus spending one or two days reading the source is probably a good idea.

As I just spent some time digging into Cooja's radio code: You could use the CustomDataRadio interface. Theoretically it should allow you to send a special object using the radio medium. Yet I didn't dig deep enough, though, to understand how it exactly works.

Comment: Thanks Morty for your response. I idea is to use out-of band radios main mote telosb at 2.4GHz and wake-up radio at 868 or sub GHz band. I will look into your suggestion of Cooja and PLC and thanks once again. I believe creating a plugin for out-of band radio will require so extra work. Cheers